# Isolation Forest get anomalies printed

Tags: python, scikit-learn, unsupervised-learning, anomaly-detection

Using Isolation Forest, as a way to find anomalies on my dataset. The dataset itself is only one column with around 8 thousand rows.
This is my code

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.ensemble import IsolationForest
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

data = pd.read_csv('MyDataset.csv')

X_train, X_test, _, _ = train_test_split(data['ColumnA'], data['ColumnA'], test_size=0.2)
clf = IsolationForest(max_samples='auto',contamination=0.003,behaviour='new') 
clf.fit(X_train.values.reshape(-1, 1))
if_scores = clf.decision_function(X_train.values.reshape(-1, 1))
if_anomalies=clf.predict(X_test.values.reshape(-1, 1))
print('Number of outliers detected:',end='')
print(sum(if_anomalies==-1))
outliers=X_test[if_anomalies==-1]

plt.scatter(X_test.index, X_test.values,c='g')
plt.scatter(outliers.index, outliers.values.reshape(1, -1),c='r')
plt.show()
```

**Explaining the code**

- Read the dataset
- Split the column/data into training and testing parts
- Run the isolation forest from scikit-learn
- Display the numbers of anomalies
- Plot the anomalies into a graph

**This is the part I am lost**

Even though I see the number of anomalies and see where they are located in the plot.
How can I get a list displayed of the numbers/values that are considered as anomalies.

Comment: your `outliers` is a numpy array of outliers. what exactly is your problem?

Comment: @Sergey Bushmanov, I want to print the values/numbers of what the anomalies are. Example one of the anomalies is number 3500. So i  want the print fucntion to print all the outliers

Comment: `print(outliers)`

Comment: @Sergey Bushmanov, I have a question that it regarding this one. Not sure if this is true " Kmeans does not tell which is the outlier and which isn't so it is impossible to plot the ROC curve. It just clusters the data " ?